# Gearbox Swap '93 model mitsubishi triton MJ

Tags: manual-transmission, mitsubishi

I bought two cars, one as a road vehicle and another as spares. They're both Mitsubishi Triton MJ. My road vehicle is a '93 model and the spare is a '94 model.

My question is whether it's possible to switch the transmissions between vehicles because one is a cable clutch and the other is a hydraulic.

cheers